# Stochastic integral with stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I'm reading a book "Introduction to random process" written by N. V. Krylov. I have a question a fact which the author does not give a proof and any references.

I have no idea to prove it or find a relevant references.

$\mathcal{S}$ denote the set of all $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted, $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}(0,\infty)$-measurable process $f_t$ such that 
$$ \int_0^t  f_s^2 ds<\infty  \quad\text{a.s. }\quad T<\infty.$$

By $H$ we denote the set of all real-valued $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted functions $f_t(\omega)$ which are $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}(0,\infty)$-measurable and satisfy 
$$   \mathbb{E}\int_0^\infty f_t^2 dt<\infty. $$

The author gives the following fact without giving a proof and any reference.

> If $f\in\mathcal{S}$, $\tau$ is a stopping time, and 
>   $$   \mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau f_s^2 ds = \mathbb{E} \int_0^\infty I_{s<\tau} f_s^2 ds<\infty,  $$
>   then $I_{s<\tau} f_s \in H$ and $\int_0^\infty I_{s<\tau} f_s dw_s$ make sense.

How can I prove this fact? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The square of indicator function is itself. Does that help? Or you are asking why the stochastic integral with respect to Brownian Motion makes sense for processes in $H$?

Comment: But this is just the definition of $H$. A less trivial fact is that $\int_0^\tau f_s dW_s = \int_0^\infty I_{s<\tau} f_s dW_s$.

Comment: @zhoraster I thought that that is a definition, isn't?

Comment: @Calculon Integrability condition is ok since the fact you mentioned. So All elements in $H$ are in Ito's integrable functions. Hence the integral make sense. Is it?

Comment: @WillKwon Yes, indeed.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you call definition. I define $\int_0^\tau f dW = \int_0^t fdW\, |_{t=\tau}$.

Comment: @zhoraster The author actually proved the fact you mentioned. I was confused. Thank you for your comments.